# Java nested for while loops

Tags: java, design-patterns, while-loop

I am having troubles with nested while loops in a for loop. I understand the nested for loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i<5;i++)
    {
        for (int j=i;j<5;j++)    
        {
           System.out.print("*"); 
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

When it comes to a while loop inside a for loop I'm kinda lost, can someone explain it to me?

```
Expected output:
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't even contain a nested `while` loop. Please add one.

Comment: Time to do some desk checking.  Get out a pen and piece of paper and walk the code, updating the values as you go...

Comment: or better than pen and paper, breakpoints!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of the equivalences between `for` loops and `while` loops, it's *basically* this:

```
for (INIT; CONDITION; POSTOP) {     INIT;
    BODY;                           while (CONDITION) {
}                                       BODY;
                                        POSTOP;
                                    }
```

(with variations for scope and other such things that we don't need to go into here).

Hence, to solve your problem with a `for/while` solution, you could use something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int j = i;
    while (j < 5) {
        System.out.print("*");
        j++;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

It's sometimes helpful to run through the code in your head, with a pen and a bit of paper to maintain variables, such as:

```
 i   j   output
--- ---  ------
```

If you just "execute" each line of the code (either your original or my `for/while` variant) in your head for a few iterations, you should see what's happening. And, if you do them side-by-side, you'll see the equivalency between both variants.

Basically, the outer loop counts (iterates) from 0 to 4 inclusive, running the inner loop then outputting a newline character.

For *each* of those iterations, the inner loop counts from `i` to 4 inclusive, outputting a `*` each time (with no newline character).

So, in the first outer loop iteration, the inner loop runs from `0` to `4`, outputting five stars.

In the second outer loop iteration, the inner loop runs from `1` to `4`, outputting four stars.

And so on, to the final outer loop iteration where `i` is `4`, so the inner loop runs from `4` to `4`, outputting one star.

In terms of the pen-and-paper method, you would get something along the following lines:

```
 i   j   output
--- ---  ------
 0   0     *
 0   1     *
 0   2     *
 0   3     *
 0   4     *
           \n
 1   1     *
 1   2     *
 1   3     *
 1   4     *
           \n
 2   2     *
 2   3     *
 2   4     *
           \n
 3   3     *
 3   4     *
           \n
 4   4     *
           \n
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first your `for` loop(s) could be written like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < 5; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Next, let's look at the three parts of a [`for` loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop) (from the Wikipedia link)

```
for(INITIALIZATION; CONDITION; INCREMENT/DECREMENT){
    // Code for the for loop's body
    // goes here.
}
```

We can move that to a `while` loop like

```
INITIALIZATION;
while (CONDITION) {
    // Code for the while loop's body
    // goes here.
    INCREMENT/DECREMENT;
}
```

As a single practical example,

```
int j = i;
while (j < 5) {
    System.out.print("*");
    j++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A while loop inside a for loop can be made to behave like a nested for loop if you simply update the counter variable within the body of the while loop. Alternatively, think about what a for loop is really saying per iteration.

```
for (int i = 0; i<5;i++)
{
    int j = i;
    // for (int j=i;j<5;j++)    
    while(j < 5)
    {
       System.out.print("*");
       j++;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```